# Concentration compactness on a compact setting

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Consider a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ and a sequence of positive functions $\{\varphi_k\}_k \in C^\infty(M)$ such that $\{\varphi_k\}_k$ satisfy the basic **concentration** compactness assumption:

$$\forall k:  \hspace{0.5cm}  \Vert \varphi_k\Vert_{L^p} = \text{constant.} \text{  }$$

And if that helps, assume that $p$ is the critical Sobolev constant, i.e. $p = 2^* = \frac{2n}{n - 2}.$

After passing to a subsequence, which we still call $\{\varphi_k\}_k$, we have weak$^*$ convergence: 
$$\varphi_k^p dM \to d\mu,\: k \rightarrow \infty,$$

where $d\mu$ is a Radon measure.

**My question is:**  Are there any known additional sufficient conditions on $\{\varphi_k\}_k$ or on the manifold $M$ that rule out **concentration** and **dichotomy**? This is mainly a reference request.

I am particularly interested in the sufficient conditions that rule out **concentration**. In other words, I want to avoid the following scenario: $$d\mu = c\delta_x,$$ where $x \in M$ and $c$ is a constant.

When I say **dichotomy**, I mean: there exists $x \in M$ and an open set $U \subset M$, $x \notin U$ such that: $$d\mu(\{ x\}) > 0, \hspace{1cm} d\mu (U) > 0.$$

Such problems come up in variational characterizations to nonlinear elliptic PDEs on manifolds with power-type nonlinearity.

Comment: You might be interested in quantum unique ergodicity, see https://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/2011/Jul11/TechPaperHassell.pdf

Comment: The usual case is when the sequence is a minimizing sequence for an energy associated with a critical Sobolev inequality. One then analyzes the limiting situation via a blow-up argument (rescaling the manifold near a point where the sequence is converging weakly to a point measure).